# Blocking automatic setting of APIPA IP on the network interface

Tags: networking, netplan

I have a VM (on ESXi) with Jammy installed; The second interface takes Apipa in Ubuntu:

```
# /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
ens192           UP             169.254.158.255/16 metric 2048
```

I have removed the interface, then attached a new one, but it again gets the same APIPA IP on ens192! I also removed that IP by the command `IP a d 169.254.158.255/16 dev ens192`, but after a reboot, it came back! How can I get rid of the APIPA IP?

```
$ ip -c -br a
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8
ens160           UP             172.17.240.2/24 metric 100
ens192           UP             169.254.90.187/16 metric 2048
```

My case: DHCP enabled (true) for ens160, and intentionally no IP for ens192

Even If I set static IP on ens192:

```
ip -c -br a
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8
ens160           UP             172.17.238.45/24 metric 100
ens192           UP             169.254.90.187/16 metric 2048 10.0.0.11/24
```

My netplan config file:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      link-local: [ ipv4 ]
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp-identifier: mac
    ens192:
      link-local: [ ipv4 ]
      dhcp4: false
      #addresses:
        #- 10.0.0.11/24
```

I'm wondering why it gets APIP?!

Comment: maby it's related to the mac address

Comment: MAC? DHCP is off and I have deleted network interfaces and added them newly!

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying `link-local: [ ipv4 ]` in your config and that is what an APIPA address is.  If you don't want this, you can specify `link-local: []` instead.